# WinSCP batch transfer with SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: batch-file, ssms, winscp, sql-server-agent

I have a .bat file that:

executes WinSCP (calls a script txt) and transfers a file through SFTP.  It also archives the file that was transferred.

My Problem is it works just fine when I double click the .bat file. BUT when I execute it in SQL Server agent job, it does archive the file but is not transffering the to the SFTP.

I get no error at all in the history of the job.

I feel it isnt executing the WinSCP or not opening the txt script. I checked permissions and it shows fine in all files and folders...

Checked FULL control for all users on all files and related folder.
Tried checking my syntax.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /command "option confirm off" 
/console /script="C:\Program Files\WinSCP\LocalToRemote.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add [`/log=C:\path\to\winscp.log` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) to WinSCP command line to see what's going on.

In a rare case the error is so fatal that even no log file is produced, you should capture WinSCP console output. You cannot do that with `winscp.exe`, you need [`winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) for that, and you should use it anyway.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
    /log=C:\path\to\winscp.log ^
    /command "option confirm off" ^
    /script="C:\Program Files\WinSCP\LocalToRemote.txt" > C:\path\to\winscp.out
```

---

Until you show us the logs, I can only point you to WinSCP FAQ:
[My script works fine when executed manually, but fails or hangs when run by Windows Scheduler, SSIS or other automation service. What am I doing wrong?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_scheduler)

The most usual problem is the first one listed in the FAQ:

> - The script fails (or “hangs”), because the [host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key) (SFTP or SCP) or [certificate](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tls#certificate) (FTPS, WebDAVS) is not known by the service’s account, and WinSCP fails (or asks for) its verification.

See also [Debugging transfer task running in Windows Scheduler, SSIS, or another automation service](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler).

---

The best what you can do it to have WinSCP GUI [generate script/command-line/batch-file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you, with all details needed for the script to be really portable.